# Nginx HTTP basic authentication with exceptions for particular IP addresses

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I'm looking to set up basic authentication for a web app I have running.

The app is using nginx 1.12.2 as well as Apache 2.2.15 (although this is a test instance and the production instance uses 1.12.2 and 2.4.6). It's all running on a CentOS 7 server.

I've been using a tutorial [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-basic/) to do this. I've managed to get the authentication working and I'm getting a pop up asking for username and password when I navigate to the site in a browser. However, I can't get the IP whitelist working - credentials are requested wherever I connect from.

The goal is that anyone on our network or connected via our VPN won't have to enter these credentials. Seems like it should be pretty straightforward, but I can't get it to work.

Essentially we need anyone in the range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255 to be able to access this, as well as the VPN addresses which are in the range 10.8.0.x.

Before attempting the IP address controls I had to play around with where in the nginx conf file I placed the authentication information to get it working and found it had to be in the section I have added it in. But, the IP controls are not working as stated. I can't see what I'm missing here.

Below are the contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf`

```
upstream myapplication-3.3.2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:18805;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root  /srv/letsencrypt;
  }
  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
        listen 18804;
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}


server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/myapplication3.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myapplication3-errors.log;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user1/.acme.sh/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.key;
        ssl_certificate /home/user1/.acme.sh/mydomain.com/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

        satisfy any;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 192.168.1.1/24;
        allow 10.8.0.0/24;
        deny all;

        auth_basic      "Authentication required";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/httpd/.htpasswd;

        client_max_body_size 0;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://myapplication-3.3.2;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the suggestions so I have established that the issue is something to do with how I am writing the IP addresses themselves. I'm able to get an exception working using 0.0.0.0/0 which is a good start, and also if I use my actual public IP address. But I can't seem to add an exception using my private/internal IP address range. I've tried a few ways including:

```
192.168.1.0/24 "off";
192.168.1.1/24 "off"
192.168.1.0/32 "off"
192.168.1.0/32 "off"
```

But I'm still being prompted for authentication when accessing the page despite my IP address being 192.168.1.22.

**EDIT** added to address question.

When I have `192.168.1.0/24 "off"`,  this is what I see in the log when trying to access the page.

```
78.432.xx.xxx - - [23/Jan/2018:14:01:19 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 401 195 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
```

Which I presume means that I'm being asked for credentials because nginx considers the public IP address to be mine. I think there must be some way to tell it to looks for both public and private/internal addresses though.

Because of this I also tried connecting using the internal IP address instead of the domain name and yes, I could connect with no credentials.

Comment: Did you look at your logs to see what nginx believes your ip is?

Comment: Edited again but in short you're question made me realise nginx is only registering my public/external IP address when I'm using the domain name to try to access the application. I need the internal/private address to be the one that's used.

Comment: I think you are going well past the scope of the original question to the point of a https://serverfault.com/ question.

Comment: I think you're right. Your answer to the original question was correct and its drifted now. I'll move to serverfault, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [geo](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html#geo) directive. This should ***with testing*** turn on and off authentication based on ip address. Just remove the allow and deny ip ranges.

```
geo $authentication {
    default "Authentication required";
    127.0.0.1 "off";
    192.168.1.1/24 "off";
    10.8.0.0/24 "off";
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        ...
        auth_basic $authentication;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying this when I have had time the last couple of days, but don't seem to be able to get it to work. The closest I can get is getting it with basic auth working, but not allowing connections from those addresses to bypass it.

Comment: Tested on one of my test sub domains like above except for the ip ranges and it did work for me. Make sure that the `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file` are inside of the location otherwise might not work right.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I keep getting the basic auth input even after whitelisting the IP

Comment: You need to put the auth_basic / auth_basic_user_file into "location"